# Is it possible to create user defined report from shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The shiny app below is taken out of gallery. It allow user to choose a variable, build a linear regression and download report.

What if I do not know in advance how many plots and models user wants to build and include into report. Is it possible to create a report with dynamically added plots?

**Server.R**

```
function(input, output) {

    regFormula <- reactive({
        as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
    })

    output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
        par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
        plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
    })

    output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
                input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
            ))
        },

        content = function(file) {
            src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

            # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
            # permission to the current working directory
            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

            library(rmarkdown)
            out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
                input$format,
                PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
            ))
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
    )

}
```

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
    title = 'Download a PDF report',
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText(),
            selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                        choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
            radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                         inline = TRUE),
            downloadButton('downloadReport')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('regPlot')
        )
    )
)
```

**report.Rmd**

````
Here is my regression model:

```{r model, collapse=TRUE}
options(digits = 4)
fit <- lm(regFormula(), data = mtcars)
b   <- coef(fit)
summary(fit)
```

The fitting result is $mpg = `r b[1]` + `r b[2]``r input$x`$.
Below is a scatter plot with the regression line.

```{r plot, fig.height=5}
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19, col = 'gray')
abline(fit, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```
````

Comment: Yes, it certainly is possible

Comment: @PeterEllis Dear Peter, could you please give me a small hint how it can be done? There is a template (report.Rmd) with a place to glue plot in (second code chunk). If I knew user wants two or ten plots I can put in template two or ten such a chunks. But what I I don't know? I can not find a way how to change template dynamically.

Comment: Is it for printing out or just viewing in the browser?

Comment: For printing or (perhaps) uploading to confluence. It should be html file.

Comment: I try to do the following:

in ui.R I put button
`actionButton("plt2rprt", label = "Include into report"),
            hr(),`

in server.R I put following:
` plist <- list()
 plotList <- eventReactive(input$plt2rprt, {
        p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes_string(x = input$x, y = "mpg")) +
            geom_point()
        plist[[length(plist)+1]] <- p
        return(plist)
    })`

Comment: In report.Rmd I put:
`do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList(),
                          ncol=floor(sqrt(length(plotList())+1)),
                          top = "test"))`

But unfortunately my list is always have only one last plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like I have found the answer. The problem was in local/global variables. I had to put list initialisation outside server function. Also I had to use `<<-` instead of `<-` to assign new element to the plot rather than create new plot every time.

Many thanks to Peter Ellis to support!

So, the solution is (I have slightly changed initial code to focus on the important part):

**server.R**

```
library(ggplot2); library(shiny); library(grid); library(gridExtra)


plist <- list() # IMPORTANT - outside server function

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
        p <- do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList(),
                                       ncol=floor(sqrt(length(plotList())+1)),
                                       top = "test"))
    })



    plotList <- eventReactive(input$plt2rprt, {
        p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes_string(x = input$x, y = "mpg")) +
            geom_point()
 #       isolate(
        plist[[length(plist)+1]] <<- p #IMPORTATNT <<- instead of <-
 #       )
        return(plist)
    })


    output$lengthOfList <- renderText({length(plotList())})
    output$lll <- renderText({length(plist)})

    output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
                input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
            ))
        },

        content = function(file) {
            src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

            library(rmarkdown)
            out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
                input$format,
                PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
            ))
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
    )

}) #ShinyServer
```

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
    title = 'Download a PDF report',
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText(),
            selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                        choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
            actionButton("plt2rprt", label = "Include into report"),
            hr(),
            radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                         inline = TRUE),
            downloadButton('downloadReport')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('regPlot'),
            #verbatimTextOutput("count"),
            hr(),
            textOutput("lengthOfList"),
            textOutput("lll"),
            helpText("test-test-test")
        )
    )
)
```

**report.Rmd**

````
Length of list of plots `r length(plotList())`

```{r plot, fig.height=5}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList(),
                          ncol=floor(sqrt(length(plotList())+1)),
                          top = "test"))
```
````

Comment: To make your code neater and avoid the global variable you could take a look at [parameterized reports](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html).